# DOMPDF, Table cell vertical align issue

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf, codeigniter-3

This code works prefect on browsers but problem is that when i fill dynamic data and generating PDF using `dompdf` then `<td>item</td>` full column goes top on cell.

What is the solution ?

Browsers shows like this [Browsers View](http://postimg.org/image/sdc23reur/) but Generated PDF by dom pdf shows like this  [Generated PDF View](http://postimg.org/image/ly8ftcir7/)

```css
body {
            font-family: "Open Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        }
        #header { position: fixed; left: 0px; width:100%; bottom: -150px; right: 0px; height: 150px; background-color: #4b94d9; color:#000; text-align: left; }
 #page-wrap {
            width: 700px;
            margin: 0 auto;
 }
        .center-justified {
            text-align: justify;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 30em;
 }
 table.outline-table {
            border: 1px solid;
            border-spacing: 0;
 }
 tr.border-bottom td, td.border-bottom {
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
 }
 tr.border-top td, td.border-top {
            border-top: 1px solid;
 }
 tr.border-right td, td.border-right {
            border-right: 1px solid;
 }
 tr.border-right td:last-child {
            border-right: 0px;
 }
 tr.center td.center {
            text-align: center;
            valign:"middle";
 }
    
 td.pad-left {
            padding-left: 5px;
            line-height: 2;
 }
 tr.right-center td, td.right-center {
            text-align: right;
            padding-right: 50px;
 }
 tr.right td, td.right {
            text-align: right;
 }
        .content > div > span{
            display:inline-block;
            width:50%; /* or choose some other value */
        }
        .contentdate > div > span{
            display:inline-block;
            width:35%; /* or choose some other value */
        }
```

```html
<table width="100%" class="outline-table">
<tbody> 
<tr class="border-bottom border-right" style="background:#353940;color:#FFF;">
   <td width="35%" class="pad-left"><strong>Item</strong></td>
   <td width="10%" style="text-align:center;"><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
   <td width="10%" class="right"><strong>Unit Cost</strong></td>
   <td width="15%" class="right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr class="border-right">
   <td class="pad-left">some item name one</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;">15</td>
   <td class="right">1500.00</td>
   <td class="right">22500.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

This code works prefect on browsers but problem is that when i fill dynamic data and generating PDF using `dompdf` then `<td>item</td>` full column goes top on cell.

What is the solution ?

Comment: The problem isn't clear from your description. Can you screen shot what you see in the browser vs. what you see in the PDF?

Comment: [Browers shows](http://postimg.org/image/sdc23reur/) but  [Generated PDF shows](http://postimg.org/image/ly8ftcir7/)

Comment: [@BrianS](http://stackoverflow.com/users/264628/brians) i have added screenshots. can you help ?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue using the HTML from your question. Can you update with the exact HTML that renders incorrectly (if needed you can get what dompdf has in memory by calling `$dompdf->output_html()`).

Comment: That being said, you're setting the line height on that first cell in all your table rows. You might want to adjust your code so that the header row doesn't have any extra formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try This.

```
td.pad-left {
        padding-left: 5px;
        //line-height: 2; <--remove this
}
```

> Html

```
    <tr class="border-right">
       <!-- give margin top in particular line -->
       <td class="pad-left"><p style="margin-top:10px;">some item name one</p></td>
       <td style="text-align:center;">15</td>
       <td class="right">1500.00</td>
       <td class="right">22500.00</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.[Vimal Mistry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4654371/vimal-mistry) It works fine.